# Delete a specific tag from main soup in BeautifulSoup4 (python)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tags

This is what i have tried - look at soup.div.decompose(), I also tried soup.elements.div.decompose(). Also this is using content from DataTables and this my first time using it so if there's a better way to achieve what i'm doing please tell me! Thanks in advace!

```
import bs4

with open('MapPage.html', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    txt = f.read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt,"html5lib")

elements = soup.find_all('tr')
elements.pop(0)

def DeleteData(msgID):
    for div in elements:
        ID = div.find('a').contents[0]
        if int(msgID)==int(ID):
            soup.div.decompose()
            return
    print('Failed to delete data from', msgID)
```

I'm hoping i'll be able to then just write the soup to the 'MapPage.html' again. The error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'` is produced.
This is the output when printing `div`:
[(Link to html file)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArSMEq2gZM7KhO02RvBtSZr-_MJGKw)
[image: This is the output when printing div]

Comment: Is your code working or not?

Comment: No - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'

Comment: Then add those details and edit the question, because asking for *a better way* is off-topic here.

Comment: Just done that now

Comment: While improving your question -> HTML / code as text would be better.

Comment: Added the link to the html file to question. Here it is here also https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArSMEq2gZM7KhO02RvBtSZr-_MJGKw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you like to `decompose()` the `<tr>` that contains a specific value in its `<a>`.

Main issue is that you try to perform `soup.div.decompose()` what means, that you like to `decompose()` first `<div>` of soup object.

Simply use:

```
div.decompose()
```

or even better change your variable name to a none tag name:

```
e.decompose()
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<html><body>
    <h2>Welcome to our collection of community made maps!</h2>
    <table id="example" class="cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>ID</th><th>Author</th><th>Content</th><th>Thumbnail</th><th>Download</th><th>Rating</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="https://discord.com/channels/932741876174454914/932881912714895390/939257309387980851">939257309387980851</a></td>
                <td>Matter</td><td>Cervinia Source</td><td><img src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/932881912714895390/939257307290796062/unknown.png" alt="Cervina Thumb" width="300" height="auto"></td><td><a href="https://discord.com/channels/932741876174454914/932881912714895390/939257309387980851">Download</a></td><td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><a href="https://discord.com/channels/932741876174454914/932881912714895390/939257309387980851">939257309387980852</a></td><td>Tea</td><td>Chamonix</td><td><img src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/932881912714895390/939257307290796062/unknown.png" alt="Cervina Thumb" width="300" height="auto"></td><td><a href="https://discord.com/channels/932741876174454914/932881912714895390/939257309387980851">Download</a></td><td>5</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body></html>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,)
elements = soup.select('tr:has(td)')

def DeleteData(msgID):
    for e in elements:
        ID = e.find('a').contents[0]
        if int(msgID)==int(ID):
            e.decompose()
            return
        print('Failed to delete data from', msgID)

DeleteData(939257309387980851)
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) 
 *Tag.decompose() removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents*